# How to detect WHILE a pane is being resize in Javafx

Tags: resize, javafx, pane

I was wondering if anyone has ideas on how to detect **WHILE** a pane is being resized.  Basically I have multiple threads drawing on the pane and would like the threads to stop while the pane is being resized. When I scroll the inside of the pane I am able to stop all threads by using a combination of setOnMouseDragged, setOnMousePressed and setOnMouseReleased and setting a boolean to true or false.  Works great!  Appreciated any examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Whenever there is a change in the width or height property it turns a boolean to true.  The threads attempting to draw pause while the boolean is true and then turn the boolean back to false after about 100ms allowing them to continue drawing.

Comment: Could you please show me some example? I'm looking for some similar solution.